# What is the hovot halevavot referring to

Tags: hovot-halevavot

In the [first gate](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/mahshevt/hovot/1-2.htm), chapter 5

He says

> כי **כבר נתברר** שכל מה שאין לו תחילה אין לו תכלה, מפני שאי אפשר להגיע בדבר שאין לו תחילה אל גבול שיעמוד האדם אצלו.

~

> since it was **already explained** that everything that does not have an end does not have a beginning ....

**Where** was it **already explained**?

Or what am I getting wrong

Comment: It is old philosophy, you can read a lot about this kind of proofs in The Critic of the pure Reason. to go up to the end is a proof tha that is a finite number of steps. If the begining is infinitely distant, you can not go to here. I suppose you learn in school mathematics that are after the remotion of  this principles, infinites etc. The world of the chovot Halevavot  kwnew an other philosophy. You are born after, so you need an introduction to understand HL and an introduction to know why it seems not obvious for you. You too are in a world and you must to know story of knowledge

Comment: @kouty I did learn a little math, I only see a problem at a first look, but when I look closer I understand that in Math there is a beginning "0". - are you saying that "already explained" means by the philosophy in his time?

Comment: שאין לו תחילה אין לו תכלה means that whatever does not have a beginning does not have "ability to affect"  ?  I think that your English is reversed in meaning.

Comment: @sabbahillel I am asking about כבר נתברר but see mrapa lnefesh here (if my English is correct) http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=41644&st=&pgnum=51

Comment: I see the reference and I would translate it (very roughly) `Anything that suffers change has a beginning, as was already explained anything that has not beginning (starting point?) does not change (or degrade).`  The English in your question reverses `beginning` and `end` or `changeability` Note that as @kouty said, this assumes knowledge of other philosophy books.

Comment: @sabbahillel I am not asking an explanation of the logic. just, what is he reffuring to when he says כבר נתברר

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He is referring to Saadia Gaon's Beliefs and Opinions. In fact, the first part of the first gate is a summery of the arguments for G-d in this work, and R. Bahya ibn Paquda recommends reading the whole version. As do I for that matter.

Specifically, he's referring to two arguments found in Beliefs and Opinions Treatises I chapter I

> it is certain that heaven and earth are both finite, because the earth is the center of the universe and the heaven revolves around it. It therefore follows, of necessity, that the force inhering in then be finite, since it is impossible for an infinite force to reside in a finite body, for such a possibility is rejected by all that is known. (A reference to Aristotle's physics.) Now since the force that maintains these two is finite, it follows necessarily that they must have a beginning and an end.

This is not about time, but it comes to the same conclusion as the argument from time. Specifically, finite things require both a beginning and an end.

> I know that there are three [distinct] periods of time: past, present, and future. Now even though the present is shorter than any moment of time, I assumed for the same of argument, that this present moment is a point, and said to myself, "Let it be supposed that a person should desire mentally to advance in time above this point. He would be unable to do it for the reason that time is infinite, and what is infinite cannot be completely traversed mentally in a fashion ascending [backward to the beginning]."
>
> Now this same reason makes it impossible for existence to have traversed infinity in descending fashion so as to reach us. But if existence had not reached us, we would not have come into being. The necessary conclusion from this premise would, then, have been that we, the company of those that are, are not, and that those that exist do not exist. Since, however, I find that I do exist, I know that existence has traversed the whole length of time until it reached me and that, if it were not for the fact that time is finite, existence could not have traversed it.

Comment: How can I find "Saadia Gaon's Beliefs and Opinions"? Is it available online?

Comment: @hazoriz only the Hebrew unfortunately. But buy the book and go down the old sephard philosophy rabbit hole. I recommend the Yale translation. It's available on Amazon.

Comment: Please help me understand "He would be unable to do it for the reason that time is infinite, and what is infinite cannot be completely traversed mentally in a fashion ascending [backward to the beginning]."

Comment: @hazoriz if time is infinite, you would not be able to count from now until the end of time as you can always count longer. You could not place a point in time after an infinite time as passed and count backwards from that time to this time.

Comment: (+1) Very interesting answer but I do not see how it is connected with the quote in my question, hoivas halevavot continues with the ideas you brought here, but I do not see clearly what he is reffuring to by the words **already explained**

Comment: @hazoriz it's a common trope to refer to things explained in other works in Arabic. The rambam uses it extensively when referring to proofs in Aristotle and other philosophers. It does not necessarily refer to something in the same work.

Comment: @hazoriz Good kvar nitbarer, for the kvar nitbarer it is a reference to demonstration. F.E. in a course of math. "It was been established than...
BTW before years I read in a philo. book "imagine that a man is comming here and he says "I just arrived from an infinite way"

Comment: @kouty sorry I do not understand, please expain

Comment: 1- in a book of scientific matter you can read "We demonstrated then... it was established then" = "כבר נתברר ש". 
2- (unrelated) I read in the past: Imagine than a man who has just arrived says: "I arrive from a place infinitely far" what will be your reaction?

Comment: @hazoriz see above

Comment: @kouty Thank you, now I understand (I am used to using the word thaT, in the place you use the word thaN)

Comment: @hazoriz yes "that" tank you

Comment: How do you look are @ray 's answer below?

Answer (score 2):

[Chovos halevovos in English](http://www.dafyomi.co.il/general/info/chovos/1-shaar_yichud/shaar_yichud.htm) seems to explain this in detail. The question has been asked for as long as philosophy has failed to answer the question.

This is the "old" paradox that can be expressed as "turtles all the way down". All the myths of the goyim basically try to explain how the "gods" created the Earth, but always then point to how the "gods" were created and then how that which came before was created until they just stop without answering the question.

Modern scientists treat this in the same way with hand waving about what happened "before" the Big Bang (or what came before the two universes collided to cause the Big Bang).

The explanation from *Tov Halevanon* points to Rav Saadia Gaon and the Rambam as among those who have already expressed this philosophy.

> There are three premises which lead to the inference that this world
>   has a Creator who created it from nothing:
>   1) A thing cannot make
>   itself.
>   2) Beginnings (causes) are limited in number; therefore,
>   they must have a First Beginning (First cause) which had no beginning
>   (cause) before it.
>   3) Anything composite must have been brought into
>   existence (cannot be eternal, i.e. without beginning).
>
> When these three premises are established, the inference will be, for
>   one who understands how to use them and combine them - that the world
>   has a Creator who created it from nothing, as we will demonstrate with
>   G-d's help.
>
> (Tov Halevanon commentary: Understand, that to clarify the roots of
>   religion, there are many different ways, but the central pillar which
>   everything depends on is the logical demonstration of the "chidush
>   haolam" (this world was brought into existence from nothing). When
>   this has been clarified, then automatically, it will be demonstrated
>   the existence of G-d who created it. Many of our Sages already
>   endeavored in this route such as Rabeinu Saadia Gaon, and Rambam
>   (Maimonides). Behold, Rambam in part 1 chapter 73 of the Moray
>   Nevuchim started to show the logical demonstration of the existence of
>   G-d and that He is the absolute Unity and not physical, but he brought
>   the proofs from the words of the philosophers, and he spoke at length
>   denigrating their views and all of their proofs. He then returned at
>   the beginning of part 2, after mentioning the words of Aristotle who
>   believed in the existence of G-d while also believing in the eternal
>   existence of the world, and along the same line of reasoning which
>   Aristotle brought for the existence of G-d and that He is one and not
>   physical. The Rambam rose to argue with him and refute his proofs on
>   the eternity of the world, and to demonstrate that Aristotle has no
>   proof on this, until just the opposite - one can prove the creation.
>   However, the author here, of blessed memory, sifted the truth from the
>   words of the philosophers, and added strength and pure hands to revive
>   the proofs for creation and to mend their breaches, and automatically
>   the existence of G-d will be demonstrated.

Answer (score 1):

the commentaries there explain:

Manoach Halevavos: "bamuskal rishon".

Marpe Lenefesh "davar ze hu barur u'muskal"

Pas Lechem: "bemuskal rishon kemo shemevaer"

Hence, the consensus seems to be that it is "muskal rishon" - self-evident. According to that the correct translation should be "it is already clear" or "it is self-evident" rather than "it was already explained".